# Getting the first 3 letters from string in cell?

Tags: swift, string, xcode, substring, tableview

I am trying to get the first 3 letters from this string but I am getting this error. Where do I go from here?

ERROR  Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

```
    let start = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
    start.text = posts[indexPath.row].start.characters.prefix(3)
```

Comment: Did you try `for index in 0..<3 { code }` and index there?

Comment: What is the type of `posts`?

Comment: Its a Struct of Strings.

Comment: I assume that the error message is just misleading, and it should be `start.text = String(posts[indexPath.row].start.characters.prefix(3))`

Comment: Thanks Martin R! It worked!